# Python script to diff same table in two different databases

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I am about to write a python script to help me migrate data between different versions of the same application.

Before I get started, I would like to know if there is a script or module that does something similar, and I can either use, or use as a starting point for rolling my own at least. The idea is to diff the data between specific tables, and then to store the diff as SQL INSERT statements to be applied to the earlier version database.

Note: This script is not robust in the face of schema changes

Generally the logic would be something along the lines of

```
def diff_table(table1, table2):
    # return all rows in table 2 that are not in table1
    pass

def persist_rows_tofile(rows, tablename):
    # save rows to file
    pass

dbnames=('db.v1', 'db.v2')
tables_to_process = ('foo', 'foobar')

for table in tables_to_process:
    table1 = dbnames[0]+'.'+table
    table2 = dbnames[1]+'.'+table
    rows = diff_table(table1, table2)

    if len(rows):
        persist_rows_tofile(rows, table)
```

Is this a good way to write such a script or could it be improved?. I suspect it could be improved by cacheing database connections etc (which I have left out - because I am not too familiar with SqlAlchemy etc).

Any tips on how to add SqlAlchemy and to generally improve such a script?

Comment: I had the same issue earlier today, and I found this guide really helpful for copying databases. http://www.tylerlesmann.com/2009/apr/27/copying-databases-across-platforms-sqlalchemy/ For your needs, I doubt you need to actually diff two tables. merge() is magical.

Answer (score 0):

To move data between two databases I use [pg_comparator](http://www.cri.ensmp.fr/~coelho/pg_comparator/pg_comparator.html). It's like diff and patch for sql! You can use it to swap the order of columns but if you need to split or merge columns you need to use something else.

I also use it to duplicate a database asynchronously. A cron-job runs every five minutes and pushes all changes on the "master"-database to the "slave"-databases. Especially handy if you only need distribute a single table, or a not all columns per table etc.

Comment: Thanks for sharing, do you know of any new publication URL? Some links are broken in the page you refer to.